# How to import lodash into a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, import, lodash, ecmascript-5, liveserver

After installing packages e.g. `lodash` using `npm install --save lodash`, I am trying to add it to the top of the file.

```
import _ from 'lodash';

console.log(add(10, 3));
```

When I start Live Server from VS Code, I get this error. I cannot figure it out how to fix it? Please help me:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "lodash". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I am trying to write the path in different ways, but it did not help me.

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Include them in your post as text.

Comment: Also please share the output of `npm -v` and the project structure, and dependency.json file contents here

Comment: Have you tried loading from the `node_modules` directory? If you are using a raw `module` and you did not bundle your code yet e.g. WebPack, you will have to change the import to something like: `import _ from '../node_modules/lodash'`

Comment: As I understand I cannot use import without any bundler like parcel or webpack ? I am trying to write this way like yo say  '../node_modules/lodash' - but it does not work I add my js file to html with `type="module"` and I thought I can add lodash without ant bundler. Npm - v  =8.19.3: json file include lodash

Answer (score 1):

You can call any method by using `_`. Example:

```
console.log(_.add(10, 3));
```